# How do I move all fields of my Work Area into my dbtab, without specifying each one?

Tags: field, move, abap

I `SELECT`ed data from a database table into an internal table and made some changes to it. Now I would like to write that data back into the database table.

Is there a way to "Move" all fields from `<wa>` to my dbtab `zcomp` at once, without specifying every field like my last line? Something like `MOVE-CORRESPONDING`, but this doesn't work properly in my case.

Thank you!

```
 SELECT * FROM zcomp
 INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_zcomp
 WHERE part = 'YX' AND target NE 'XY'.

LOOP AT it_zcomp ASSIGNING <wa>.
  <wa>-part = 'YX'.
ENDLOOP.

MOVE <wa>-field1 TO zcomp-field1.
```

I don't want to change existing lines. I rather want to copy and move them into a new line (from the same dbtab). I tried to use `MOVE-CORRESPONDING zcomp to zcom`, but that caused an error. And when I use `MOVE-CORRESPONDING wa to zcomp`, then the rest of my code stops working.

Comment: I might have a solution for you. Can you be more specific about what exactly "doesn't work properly" with `MOVE-CORRESPONDING` in your specific use-case?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, you only have a couple hours to reply, or you will have to wait for my answer until Monday :)

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to change existing lines rather copy and move them into a new line (from the same dbtab). So, @Philipp I can't use `MOVE-CORRESPONDING zcomp to zcomp`. And when I use `MOVE-CORRESPONDING wa to zcomp`, then the rest of my code stops working.

Comment: @Notion So what you are actually mean to ask is how you write the data you have in `it_zcomp` back from RAM into the database? What's the type of `it_zcomp`? Is it `TYPE TABLE OF zcomp`?

Comment: @Philipp yes, this is correct. `DATA it_zcomp TYPE TABLE OF zcomp`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that data in memory ("internal tables" or "itabs") and data in the database ("database tables", "transparent tables" or "dbtabs") are accessed and modified through different syntax. The `MOVE-CORRESPONDING` instruction can only be used to move data from memory to memory. It can not be used to move data from memory to database or from database to memory.

In order to write new rows from an internal table to a database table, you can use `INSERT zcomp FROM TABLE it_zcomp`. This will create a new row in the database table `zcomp`for each entry in the internal table `it_zcomp`. But keep the primary key of the database table in mind! Remember that there can only be one entry per database table with the same values in the primary key fields fields! When there is already a row with the same primary key as one of the values in the table, then no data will be inserted and an exception `CX_SY_OPEN_SQL_DB` will be thrown (you can suppress the exception with the addition `ACCEPTING DUPLICATE KEYS` - but that will only result in the duplicate lines being skipped which might not be your intention either).

If you want to update the rows with primary keys which are already in the database table and create new rows for those primary keys which do not exist yet, then you might want to use `MODIFY zcomp FROM TABLE it_zcomp` instead. This instruction performs an "upsert". It updates data which is already there and inserts data which isn't.

But this means that if you changed the primary key of any of the rows you got from the database, then the entry with the old primary key will remain. If you want to *change* the primary key values of one or more rows, you first have to use `DELETE` with the old primary key values to delete the existing entries and then `INSERT` the rows with the new values.